# how to use vscode extension to hide timeline and outline in the side bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The photo of timeline and outline is below. I want to hide them by vscode extension.

[image: outline and timeline views]

Comment: just use the menu at the top of the Bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those views all have a `remove` command, so in an extension you could do this:

```js
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('timeline.removeView');
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('outline.removeView');
```

That works in my testing.

Answer (score 3):

It's work for you:
right click on the `Timeline` or `Outline`, then you can deselect `Timeline` and `Outline`.